# Handlebars helper must return value if the value is

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have created Handlebars helper like this:

In my JS file:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('switch', function (sw_val, options) {
    if (sw_val != '*NONE' && sw_val != false && sw_val != "" && sw_val) {
        return this
    }
    return this;
});
```

In my template:

```
{{switch sw_val}} {{sw_val}} {{/switch}}
```

The idea is that if there is sw_val value, then let it appears.
But it doesn't work.
What I need to return to get value?

Comment: Read the documentation, that's not how you create a block helper...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('switch', function (sw_val, options) {
    if (sw_val != '*NONE' && sw_val != false && sw_val != "" && sw_val) {
      return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Comment: Although this solves the problem for the OP it really should have had some more explanation to it.